# iOS - Change only backBarButtonItem text color on a navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to change the color of the backBarButtonItem on a navigation bar in my app (iOS 9+).

I can do this with :

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But this will change the color for all UIBarButtonItems on the navigation bar and I only want to change the back button.

I have tried :

```
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and

```
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But it doesn't work

NOTE: I want to keep the < arrow of the system back button so using a custom view is not an option unless I use a custom image

Comment: you can use custom view, if possible

Comment: @MikeAlter is right we can use custom view UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourUIButton]

Comment: There's no way to just change the color of a specific bar button item on the nav bar?

Comment: Try changing color in `viewWillAppear`. It works for me!
In VC 1 `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red` and in VC 2 `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white` gives back button with red and white color respectively.

Comment: Please read my question before answering

Comment: You asked : "I'm trying to change the color of the backBarButtonItem on a navigation bar in my app (iOS 9+)."  Code mentioned in my above comment will do the same, it will change navigation bar back button to required color. Whats wrong ?

Comment: I asked to change ONLY the back button color. Your method will change all button colors

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used the following solution:

**1.** Set the general appearance of UIBarbuttonitem **BEFORE** adding the right bar button item

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**2.** Then set the right bar button item and its specific appearance

```
UIBarButtonItem *rigthBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(rightBtnTapped:)];

[rigthBtn setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rigthBtn];
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment posting sample code

```
    UIButton *useButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    useButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20,17);
    useButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    useButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 3);
    useButton.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
    useButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1;
    useButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    useButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    useButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [useButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image if any"] forState:0];
    [useButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:useButton]];
```

`

Comment: This wont use the back button image

Answer (score 0):

One year too late but did you tried to set the tintColor? I dont know your syntax but in swift it would be:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.COLOR
```